# how to prove Bayes theorem?

Tags: conditional-probability

how to prove Bayes theorem? (Develop from conditional probability )
2 criterias
-Total of law is probability 
-multiplication rule 
Can someone show me the mathematical proof & steps for this please?

Comment: There's a perfectly good proof on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Derivation).  Are there steps there that you don't follow and would like more explanation on?

Comment: There isn't much to prove at all...

Answer (score 3):

The conditional probability is defined as
$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)},
$$
hence
$$
P(A|B) P(B) = P(B|A) P(A) .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints

- Write $P(A \cap B)$ two different ways using conditional probability
- these are therefore equal by Euclid's first axiom
- manipulate into Bayes' theorem (assuming none of the probabilities are $0$)